# Merge two queries sql into one mapping to POCO

Tags: sql

I have two sql queries as follows

```
SELECT ADGroupName, ADGroupDescription, ADGroupEmail
FROM ADGroup 
WHERE ADGroupName = 'XXXX'
```

This returns me a single result of information about a particular group.

```
SELECT ADUser.ADUserFirstName as FirstName, ADUser.ADUserLastName as 
LastName 
FROM ADUser WHERE ADUser.ADUserName 
IN(SELECT ADUser_ADGroup.ADUGUserName 
FROM ADUser_ADGroup 
WHERE ADUser_ADGroup.ADUGGroupName = 'XXXX_Manager')
```

This returns me a list of Managers for the group I got information about in above query. Is it possible to merge both queries into one sql query?

Whole code is as follow

```
public AdGroupDto GetGroupByGroupName(string groupName)
{
    var sql = "SELECT ADGroupName, ADGroupDescription, ADGroupEmail " +
     "FROM ADGroup " +
     "WHERE ADGroupName = @0";

    var result = _db.Single<AdGroupDto>(sql, groupName);

    var sqlForTeacher = "SELECT ADUser.ADUserFirstName as FirstName, ADUser.ADUserLastName as LastName " +
    "FROM ADUser WHERE ADUser.ADUserName " +
    "IN(SELECT ADUser_ADGroup.ADUGUserName " +
    "FROM ADUser_ADGroup " +
    "WHERE ADUser_ADGroup.ADUGGroupName = @0)";

    var data = _db.Query<UserInfoDto>(sqlForTeacher, groupName + "_Manager").ToList();

   result.Teachers = data;

    return result;
}
```

Silke --    Kruse --    ZZA-KL-1A --    Pupils of the ZZA-KL-1A class
Sille --    Dahl --     ZZA-KL-1A --    Pupils of the ZZA-KL-1A class

Comment: Sure, just join three tables: ADUser, ADUser_ADGroup and ADGroup.

Comment: Can I get an example?

Comment: Does ADUser_ADGroup have foreign keys to the other 2 tables? F.e. fields like ADGroupID, ADUserID ? Because then you could join ADUser_ADGroup to the other tables on those fields.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Just posted an answer.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov checking it now

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov I updated the question with a bit more details

Answer (score 1):

If I got your tables structure correctly, and assuming you have foreign keys in every table, something like this should solve your problem:

```
SELECT ADUser.ADUserFirstName AS FirstName, ADUser.ADUserLastName AS LastName, ADGroupName, ADGroupDescription, ADGroupEmail
FROM ADUser
INNER JOIN ADUser_ADGroup ON ADUser.<id> = ADUser_ADGroup.<user_id>
INNER JOIN ADGroup ON ADGroup.<id> = ADUser_ADGroup.<group_id>
WHERE ADGroup.ADGroupName = 'XXXX' AND ADUser_ADGroup.ADUGGroupName LIKE '%Manager%'
```

Just make sure to use specific column names for the `JOIN` clauses.

UPD: It's a code for MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue is that it returns me two rows now. To avoid this I was making two queries. The result I got with queries is that I got a Group object having a list of Managers. With this query I get two Group objects.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Could you provide the two rows the query returns?

Comment: added that in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT      U.ADUserFirstName as FirstName, U.ADUserLastName as LastName, G.ADGroupName, G.ADGroupDescription, G.ADGroupEmail, 
FROM        ADUser U
INNER JOIN  ADUser_ADGroup UG ON U.ADUserName = UG.ADUGUserName
INNER JOIN  ADGroup G ON UG.ADUGGroupName = G.ADGroupName + '_Manager'
WHERE       G.ADGroupName = 'XXXX'
```

This will compare the group name with the `ADUser_ADGroup` appended with `_Manager`

Above query is for SQL Server.

If you are using Oracle:

```
SELECT      U.ADUserFirstName as FirstName, U.ADUserLastName as LastName, G.ADGroupName, G.ADGroupDescription, G.ADGroupEmail, 
FROM        ADUser U
INNER JOIN  ADUser_ADGroup UG ON U.ADUserName = UG.ADUGUserName
INNER JOIN  ADGroup G ON UG.ADUGGroupName = G.ADGroupName || '_Manager'
WHERE       G.ADGroupName = 'XXXX'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Have you tried the query? You may replace 'XXXX' with @0 as shown in your code. So you just use that `sqlForTeacher` and user `groupName` only as the parameter.  If you get any error, please let me know.